# MySQL : sum of every day

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table as follow:

```
datetime (datetime)  count (int)
2012-12-27 09:22:15    5
2012-12-27 18:20:15    4
2012-12-27 23:19:15    3
2012-12-26 13:45:15    8
2012-12-26 04:56:15    7
2012-12-25 01:50:15    2
2012-12-25 12:02:15    1
```

In MySQL, how do I query if I wish to return sum(count) for everyday and result like below:

```
2012-12-27    12
2012-12-26    15
2012-12-25    3
```

Comment: What have you tried? What hasn't worked? What research have you done to solve this problem?

Comment: It seems that the real questions here is how to you SUM a field that has the name of a reserved SQL word.  SUM(COUNT) will not work.  As noted by JW SUM('count') is the way.  Put the reserved word in quotes.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

you need to use `DATE` function around the columnName `DateTime`.

```
SELECT    DATE(datetime) as DATE, SUM(`count`) totalCOunt
FROM      tableName
GROUP BY  DATE(datetime)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68bef/1)

Comment: you're welcome. merry christmas and a happy new year to you! `:D`

Comment: gem. where would we all be without SO and answers like these.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

```
SELECT SUM(`count`) as date_count 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY date_format( `datetime`, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Note: If possible, avoid the usage of Keywords (count) as column names.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following to include the sum:

```
SELECT    DATE(datetime) day, 
SUM(`count`) Count_for_day 
FROM      tableName
GROUP BY  DATE(datetime)
```