# MySQL Sum of Every Day

Tags: mysql, sql

This is related to a post at this link:

[MySQL : sum of every day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049729/mysql-sum-of-every-day)

```
datetime (datetime)  count (int)
2012-12-27 09:22:15    5
2012-12-27 18:20:15    4
2012-12-27 23:19:15    3
2012-12-26 13:45:15    8
2012-12-26 04:56:15    7
2012-12-25 01:50:15    2
2012-12-25 12:02:15    1
```

I would like to sum the COUNT of everyday, but not only for those days where there is entry, but also those days where there is no entry.

```
SELECT    DATE(datetime) as DATE, SUM(`count`) totalCOunt
FROM      tableName
GROUP BY  DATE(datetime)
```

Code above only returns me those days where there is entry.

Say I want to get every day total of count between month of April 2016 through February 2017, how would I do it? Thanks. Example:

```
2012-12-25     25
2012-12-26     NULL --> because there is no entry
```

Comment: You can't select what isn't there. Maybe there's some hacky solution with a join to a generated list? But probably not. I say you'd need a list of all days in your database.

Comment: Use a calendar table.  You can Google for this, and you'll find many things.

Comment: so you want sum of count from min date to max date in the table. Is that right?

Comment: @Avi That is correct. Sum of Count per day. even when there is no count / entry on that day. I think Tim Biegeleisen answers it. I will have to find out how to use it and join the tables

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in below code.You can create calendar table.Which provide us exact calendar as we required.
Make entry into that calendar table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS time_dimension;

CREATE TABLE time_dimension (
        id                      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  -- year*10000+month*100+day
        db_date                 DATE NOT NULL,
        year                    INTEGER NOT NULL,
        month                   INTEGER NOT NULL, -- 1 to 12
        day                     INTEGER NOT NULL, -- 1 to 31
        quarter                 INTEGER NOT NULL, -- 1 to 4
        week                    INTEGER NOT NULL, -- 1 to 52/53
        day_name                VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL, -- 'Monday', 'Tuesday'...
        month_name              VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL, -- 'January', 'February'...
        holiday_flag            CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'f' CHECK (holiday_flag in ('t', 'f')),
        weekend_flag            CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'f' CHECK (weekday_flag in ('t', 'f')),
        event                   VARCHAR(50),
        UNIQUE td_ymd_idx (year,month,day),
        UNIQUE td_dbdate_idx (db_date)

) Engine=MyISAM;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS fill_date_dimension;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE fill_date_dimension(IN startdate DATE,IN stopdate DATE)
BEGIN
    DECLARE currentdate DATE;
    SET currentdate = startdate;
    WHILE currentdate < stopdate DO
        INSERT INTO time_dimension VALUES (
                        YEAR(currentdate)*10000+MONTH(currentdate)*100 + DAY(currentdate),
                        currentdate,
                        YEAR(currentdate),
                        MONTH(currentdate),
                        DAY(currentdate),
                        QUARTER(currentdate),
                        WEEKOFYEAR(currentdate),
                        DATE_FORMAT(currentdate,'%W'),
                        DATE_FORMAT(currentdate,'%M'),
                        'f',
                        CASE DAYOFWEEK(currentdate) WHEN 1 THEN 't' WHEN 7 then 't' ELSE 'f' END,
                        NULL);
        SET currentdate = ADDDATE(currentdate,INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    END WHILE;
END
//
DELIMITER ;

TRUNCATE TABLE time_dimension;

CALL fill_date_dimension('2000-01-01','2018-01-01');
```

Once that calendar table is created, you can write below query and it will resolve your issue.

```
SELECT COUNT(datetime) ,DB_DATE FROM time_dimension TD
LEFT JOIN TABLENAME TN ON DATE(TN.datetime)=TD.db_date
WHERE TD.DB_DATE BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-05-30'
GROUP BY  DATE(DB_DATE);
```

Hope this will helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SumCountAllDays;

DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE SumCountAllDays( startDate DATE,
                                      endDate DATE )
    BEGIN
        DECLARE daysCount INT;
        DECLARE daysIndex INT DEFAULT 0;

        SELECT DATEDIFF( endDate,
                         startDate )
        INTO daysCount;

        SET @selectStatementString := CONCAT( "SELECT allDays.intervalDate AS `Date`,",
                                              "       COALESCE( SUM( `count` ), 0 ) AS totalCount ",
                                              "FROM ( SELECT '",
                                              startDate,
                                              "' AS intervalDate" );

        daysLister : LOOP
            SET daysIndex = daysIndex + 1;
            IF daysIndex <= daysCount THEN
                SET @selectStatementString := CONCAT( @selectStatementString,
                                                      " UNION SELECT '",
                                                      DATE_ADD( startDate,
                                                                INTERVAL daysIndex DAY ),
                                                      "'" );
                ITERATE daysLister;
            END IF;
            LEAVE daysLister;
        END LOOP daysLister;

        SET @selectStatementString := CONCAT( @selectStatementString,
                                              " ) AS allDays ",
                                              "LEFT JOIN tableName ON allDays.intervalDate = DATE( `datetime` ) ",
                                              "GROUP BY allDays.intervalDate;" );

        PREPARE selectStatement FROM @selectStatementString;
        EXECUTE selectStatement;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE selectStatement;
   END //
DELIMITER ;
```

The first line is handy for when you have been fiddling with the code and you wish to remove an old version.

The rest of the code creates a procedure that when called and passed the start and end dates of the period in question starts by using `DATEDIFF()` to calculate the number of days between and including `startDate` and `endDate`, storing the value in `daysCount`.

The procedure then initialises `@selectStatementString` to the first part of our eventual statement.  This first part ends with the first of a series of `SELECT` statements that are used to select each of the dates between and including `startDate` and `endDate`.  This `SELECT` of the initial value of `startDate` is where the field formed by the union of all these dates is given its name of `intervalDate`.

The loop then appends a `SELECT` for each of the dates, which are computed based upon the loop's index, `daysIndex`.

The `UNION` operator is used to perform a vertical join on each generated date.

After the `LOOP` is finished the rest of the statement is appended to the statement so far.  If `startDate` and `endDate` were `2012-02-13` and `2012-02-15`, then we would now have the following statement...

```
SELECT allDays.intervalDate AS `Date`,
       COUNT( `count` ) AS totalCount
FROM ( SELECT '2012-02-13' AS intervalDate
       UNION
       SELECT '2012-02-14'
       UNION
       SELECT '2012-02-15' ) AS allDays
LEFT JOIN tableName ON allDays.intervalDate = DATE( `datetime` )
GROUP BY allDays.intervalDate;
```

I tested my statement against a test database created using the following script...

```
CREATE TABLE tableName
(
    `datetime`   DATETIME,
    `count`      INT
);
INSERT INTO tableName ( `datetime`,
                        `count` )
VALUES ( '2012-12-27 09:22:15', 5 ),
       ( '2012-12-27 18:20:15', 4 ),
       ( '2012-12-27 23:19:15', 3 ),
       ( '2012-12-26 13:45:15', 8 ),
       ( '2012-12-26 04:56:15', 7 ),
       ( '2012-12-25 01:50:15', 2 ),
       ( '2012-12-25 12:02:15', 1 );
```

I called the procedure using the following statement...

```
CALL SumCountAllDays( '2012-12-01',
                      '2012-12-31' );
```

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.