# How to group data in mySQL on daily basis?

Tags: mysql

I have mySQL tables with DATATIME column and I would like to aggregate them on Daily basis.

```
-----+----------------------+------------------+----------------+
  id +       datetime       +    value (int)   +  description   +
-----+----------------------+------------------+----------------+
  1  + 2019-01-01 15:15:15  +      120         +      demo1     +
  2  + 2019-01-01 17:17:17  +      240         +      demo2     +
  3  + 2019-01-02 18:15:15  +      200         +      demo3     +
  4  + 2019-01-02 19:17:17  +      300         +      demo4     +
-----+----------------------+------------------+----------------+
```

So I need the result:

```
2019-01-01 : 360 (120+240)
2019-01-02 : 500 (200+300)
```

Comment: ``SELECT DATE(`datetime`) `date`, SUM(value) sum_value FROM tablename GROUP BY DATE(`datetime`)``.

Comment: @Akina Thank you, it works excellent. Could you please to form an answer for I able to mark it green mark.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL : sum of every day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049729/mysql-sum-of-every-day)